# Custom SELECT @Query json keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm doing a JPQL query, something like this

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserFlightDao extends CrudRepository<UserFlight, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT uf.departureGps, uf.flight.id, uf.flight.flightNumber, uf.flight.airline.name, uf.flight.departureDate, " +
            "uf.flight.departureAirport.name FROM UserFlight uf WHERE user.id=?1")
    List<UserFlight> getUserFlights(Long userId);
}
```

`UserFlight` contains a `Flight` object, I select values from both `UserFlight` and `Flight` objects and return them to the user as json.

First thing, I think it's wrong to use `List<UserFlight>` as the return type (even though it works) because technically I'm not returning full `UserFlight` objects. Right? Maybe I should switch to `List<Object>`.

Second thing, I want the json returned to the user to contain key names. Currently I get json that contains an array of the objects, without their respective key names. Response example:

```
[
  [
    "sdf",
    1,
    234234,
    "American Airline",
    {
      "dayOfMonth": 13,
      "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
      "dayOfYear": 286,
      "monthValue": 10,
      "month": "OCTOBER",
      "year": 2015,
      "hour": 18,
      "minute": 41,
      "nano": 0,
      "second": 39,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    },
    "dummy airport"
  ],
  [
    "asfsaf",
    1,
    234234,
    "American Airline",
    {
      "dayOfMonth": 13,
      "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
      "dayOfYear": 286,
      "monthValue": 10,
      "month": "OCTOBER",
      "year": 2015,
      "hour": 18,
      "minute": 41,
      "nano": 0,
      "second": 39,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    },
    "dummy airport"
  ]
]
```

Any idea how can I get key names along with the values? Should I construct the json manually after receiving the `List<Object>` from the repository or is there a simpler way?

This is how I call `getUserFlights`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_flights", method = RequestMethod.POST) List<UserFlight> getUserFlights() {
        return userFlightDao.getUserFlights(new Long(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only the subset of the columns as that of the UserFlight, you need to create a lighter version of the Entity `UserFlight`, name it `UserFlightLight`. Return this entity for the above query. This may be a little work, but that can really help you to avoid all the other issues you might see for returning Object type.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I created a class to hold the values like you suggested (the class have no annotations, only setters/getters for the columns subset) and I used `SELECT new com.foo.bar.model.UserFlightLight(arg1,arg2..etc)` in the jpql query, and all is good.